# Running a quick code test in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a plugin in eclipse where can type in a quick java code sample and run it? I remember seeing something like this a  long time ago.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237987/storing-code-snippets-in-eclipse/238042#238042 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529391/eclipse-compiling-executing-program/531339#531339

Comment: @VonC Sometimes not knowing what something is called, causes you to not find the right answers. Scrapbook whas this one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the **Scrapbook**:

[image]

You need to explicitly reference all class files using a full package name, but you can get around this by importing all the libraries (including the JRE libraries) you need onto the runtime classpath.

Comment: Thanks, for those who are looking for more detail, its under File > New > other > Java > Java Run/Debug. Select a parent project and type a name for the scriptlet. Just above it there is a function to run it.